# Break a List<Object> into lists of a known set of derived types

Tags: java, downcast, visitor-pattern

Let's say that I have an argument like `List<Object> objectList`, which is provided to me externally, and that I have absolutely no control over.  Let's also say that I know every single possibility for the downcasted types of each element in this List.  For example, let's say I know that `objectList` contains elements of these types: `int, String, double, boolean`.

What approaches could I use to filter `objectList` into separate lists of each downcasted type *without* using `instanceof`.  So for this example, I want to put `objectList` into something that looks like this:

```
class SpecificTypes
{
   List<Integer> intList;
   List<String> stringList;
   List<Double> doubleList;
   List<Boolean> booleanList;
}
```

So say I want to write a function that looks like this:

```
SpecificTypes filterObjectList(List<Object> objectList)
{
   SpecificTypes results = new SpecificTypes();

   // Populate 'results' somehow
   // Without using cascading if/else or switch logic

   return results;
}
```

My research quickly led me to the visitor pattern, but I have come to the conclusion that I cannot use this because I would need control over the types stored in `objectList` (or at least be able to wrap them in my own derived types), but these are supplied to me from an external source so the visitor pattern seems impossible (right?).

The subset of derived types in the object list is fairly small (although in reality it's larger than the 4 in this example), and those types will *not* be changing.  So it's OK if I need to write multiple specializations and dispatchers.  I am trying to avoid any sort of cascading if/else or switch statement.

Is there some way to specialize functions that would sort these out properly?

Comment: You can't have a list of primatives...

Comment: Why don't you want to use instanceof?

Comment: I assume that you mean `List<Ineger>`, not `List<int>`.

Comment: Without instanceof this seems impossible. Unless you try explicitly casting each and throwing an exception

Comment: Edited out the primitives.  All of the above is just exemplary code of desired functionality.

Comment: And the reason for wishing to avoid cascading 'instanceof' occurrences is that this code will run very frequently in a fast streaming context, and I want it to be as fast as possible.  I am new to Java (from a C++ background) where tricky template programming can be utilized to solve these types of problems (see boost::any and boost::variant).

Comment: @ConTheMan `boost::any` is rather slow, why are you accepting a `List<Object>` in the first place? Although, keep in mind that because of JIT compilation, you may get surprising perfomance results once the JIT learns your code's patterns.

Comment: The `List<Object>` is given to me by an external library as the result of a database query that contains mixed types.  You all have convinced me that `instanceof` is the way to go, so I am satisfied with that and it will suit my purposes just fine.  I was just thinking that maybe there was a way to adapt the visitor pattern to my purposes, but I was mistaken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, by `List<Object> objectList` you are telling the language you forfeit type safety of anything that is more specific than `Object` which is about everything in Java.

You have to perform `instanceof` checks on the types you want to match. You have to perform casts because this is effectively what you're doing - casting. Hacks around it won't help.

Comment: @ConTheMan Well, `List<T>` is a type that depends on T, by doing `List<Object>` you are specifically telling your compiler you have a list of well... objects. If you're asking anything from these items that an `Object` can't do, you're basically breaking the object interface and telling the compiler "Well I lied, I actually have hindsight about these objects, they're really..." , telling that to the compiler is explicitly what a _cast_ is.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to do each possible cast, and if it don't fail add that element to the relevant list.

Then you just need to catch the ClassCastException. But really: Using instanceof is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is using the Class.isInstance() method instead of using the operator instanceof.

```
if (Boolean.class.isInstance(obj)){
  // handle this type
}
```

To make it more flexible, you could define an Handler base class which handles a specific class and populate a list with an instance of a specific handler for each type you support in your objectList.

Then for each object in objectList you iterate through your list of handlers calling a method isHandling() which would return true if its the supported type of the handler. This method would use the isInstance() method to check the type. If true, then you could call another method to do the handling. That way, if a new type needs to be supported you only have to derive a new handler for this type and register it in the list of handlers and that's it.

```
public abstract class Handler {

  protected Class<?> type;

  protected Handler(Class<?> type) {
    this.type = type;
  }

  public boolean isHandling(Object obj) {
    return type.isInstance(obj);
  }

  public abstract void handle(Object obj);
}
```